# How to save product url to shop_order with WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm displaying a lot of identical products on different posts with WooCommerce 2.2.6 and Wordpress 4.0, I need to store the url that is displaying the image when it is added to the cart to the backend order as meta data that I can pull to populate a custom order. I have tried the woocommerce filters woocommerce_new_order and woocommerce_new_order_data and have gotten errors. Is there another filter/hook that I can use that I am over?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow..check how to ask a question here http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Thank you @Varsha, I have gone through the help center prior to asking this question, I'm trying to find which hook I should be using for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a workaround if anyone else is interested in knowing how to get the url of a page with nested products when an order is placed. The code is pretty self explanatory:

```
        //get Cookie function
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i].trim();
            if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
         }
        return "";
    }

    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    if(pathname.indexOf('reps')>-1) {
        var rep_name = pathname.split('/');

        for(var i = 0; i<=rep_name.length; ++i) {
            if(rep_name[i]) {
                if(rep_name[i]!='reps') {
                    var rep = rep_name[i];
                    document.cookie="rep="+rep+"; path=/";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(pathname.indexOf('checkout')>-1) {
        var order_comments = $('#order_comments');
        if(order_comments) {
            var cookie = document.cookie;

            if(cookie.indexOf('rep')>-1) {

                var cookie_rep = getCookie('rep');
                order_comments.text('Rep Code:'+cookie_rep);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

And when you want to pull the information pull the order excerpt. If anyone knows a better way to do this let me know.